# How to Avoid Corrupted Downloads when Using the export links through Google Drive API in Python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs

I have a python script which downloads the files from fetching the export link from google drive api. So, using "f.write(response.content)" sometimes the file gets downloaded correctly, while sometimes it is corrupted of size 147 Bytes, so how to resolve it?

I tried running the script at two other times to ensure if the problem is with internet or not, and I found that at both the times, different sets of files were downloaded uncorrupted. For instance, first time I had runned the script, 'file_a.docx' (The converted form of a Google doc file) downloaded corrupted, while the second time this file downloaded properly. So, what can be the possible issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with authorization. By default, OAuth 2.0 access tokens are valid for a maximum of 1 hour (3,600 seconds). However, you can extend the maximum lifetime for these tokens to 12 hours (43,200 seconds). So, it was post an hour that all files post this were getting downloaded corrupted.
To resolve, either this link can be followed to increase the lifetime of access token or change the script to refresh the token after an hour.
Please ensure that there is currently a limit of 50 refresh tokens per user account per client. If the limit is reached, creating a new token automatically invalidates the oldest token without warning. This limit does not apply to service accounts. There is also a larger limit on the total number of tokens a user account or service account can have across all clients.